# How to show a menu on customers account conditionally?

Tags: magento2, frontend

I have created a custom menu on customer account. I want to show the menu only when a specific customer attribute value is set. I am not able to find out whether there is any way to show the menu **conditionally** in Magento2?

To show the custom menu, I am using this in *view/layout/frontend/customer_account.xml*

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-customfield-index-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">mymodule/customfields</argument>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Identity Proof</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First You need create block extents class **Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current**

After that use use it in to your template **view/layout/frontend/customer_account.xml** like this

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
    <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-customfield-index-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">mymodule/customfields</argument>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Identity Proof</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Then overwrite function *toHtml()* like this

```
public function toHtml(){
      if($this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getYourAttribute()){
           return parent::toHtml();
      }
      return '';
}
```

Which full block code

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Block\View\Element\Html\Link;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;

class Current extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current{

    protected $_customerSession;
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\DefaultPathInterface $defaultPath
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\DefaultPathInterface $defaultPath,
        CustomerSession $CustomerSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_defaultPath = $defaultPath;
        $this->_customerSession = $CustomerSession;
    }


    public function toHtml(){
          if($this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getYourAttribute()){
               return parent::toHtml();
          }
          return '';
    }  
}
```

Comment: This worked but I had to fix the error 

"Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Framework\App\DefaultPathInterface, array given, called in"

Did this by changing 
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
to
        parent::__construct($context, $defaultPath);

Comment: just run setup:di:compile :)

Comment: When I do that I get Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Framework\App\DefaultPathInterface. Actual type: array; File:
F:/dev/core/app/code/Company/Module/Block/MagentoExtends/View/Element/Html/Link/CurrentLoggedOut.php though :(

Comment: please remove var/di var/generation. and run compile again, make sure namespace correct.

Comment: parent::__construct($context, $data); to parent::__construct($context, $defaultPath);

I saw you have changed that. Please **parent::__construct($context, $data);** is default magento contructor don't change this.