# Magento 2 customer dashboard link show for particular user?

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account, dashboard, logging

I would like to show the customer dashboard **"Pay trade customer link"** to particular user **(Ex: example@gmail.com)** i have followed this link [Add New inbox tab in customer my dashboard in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108421/add-new-inbox-tab-in-customer-my-dashboard-in-magento-2)   for adding the custom link in the customer dashboard. hence i have created a new custom module and did the changes accordingly.

**Please find the screenshot:**

[image]

Please suggest me how i can do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please check the below code.

step 1
path - app/code/Training/Msg/registration.php

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,'Training_Msg',__DIR__);
```

step 2
path - app/code/Training/Msg/etc/module.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Training_Msg" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

step 3
path - app/code/Training/Customerlink/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" type="Training\Msg\Block\Current"/>
</config>
```

step 4
path - app/code/Training/Msg/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="msg" frontName="msg">
            <module name="Training_Msg"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

step 5
path - app/code/Training/Msg/Controller/Index/Msg.php

```
<?php
namespace Training\Msg\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Msg extends Action
{
    private $jsonFactory;

    private $pageFactory;


    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        JsonFactory $jsonFactory,
        PageFactory $pageFactory
    ){
        $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        //$result = $this->jsonFactory->create();
        $result = $this->pageFactory->create();
        $result->getConfig()->getTitle()->set("Welcome Msg");
        //$data = ['msg' => 'tets'];
        //return $result->setData($data);
        return $result;
    }

}
```

step 6
path - app/code/Training/Msg/Block/Current.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Training\Msg\Block;

/**
 * Block representing link with two possible states.
 * "Current" state means link leads to URL equivalent to URL of currently displayed page.
 *
 * @method string                          getLabel()
 * @method string                          getPath()
 * @method string                          getTitle()
 * @method null|array                      getAttributes()
 * @method null|bool                       getCurrent()
 * @method \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current setCurrent(bool $value)
 */
class Current extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * Default path
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\DefaultPathInterface
     */
    protected $_defaultPath;

    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\DefaultPathInterface $defaultPath
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\DefaultPathInterface $defaultPath,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_defaultPath = $defaultPath;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    /**
     * Get href URL
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHref()
    {
        return $this->getUrl($this->getPath());
    }

    /**
     * Get current mca
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private function getMca()
    {
        $routeParts = [
            'module' => $this->_request->getModuleName(),
            'controller' => $this->_request->getControllerName(),
            'action' => $this->_request->getActionName(),
        ];

        $parts = [];
        foreach ($routeParts as $key => $value) {
            if (!empty($value) && $value != $this->_defaultPath->getPart($key)) {
                $parts[] = $value;
            }
        }
        return implode('/', $parts);
    }

    /**
     * Check if link leads to URL equivalent to URL of currently displayed page
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isCurrent()
    {
        return $this->getCurrent() || $this->getUrl($this->getPath()) == $this->getUrl($this->getMca());
    }

    /**
     * Render block HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {

        if (false != $this->getTemplate()) {
            return parent::_toHtml();
        }

        $highlight = '';

        if ($this->getIsHighlighted()) {
            $highlight = ' current';
        }

        if ($this->isCurrent()) {
            $html = '<li class="nav item current">';
            $html .= '<strong>'
                . $this->escapeHtml((string)new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($this->getLabel()))
                . '</strong>';
            $html .= '</li>';
        } else {
            if( $this->customerSession->getCustomerGroupId() == 1 ){
            if ( strpos($this->getHref(),'msg') == false ) {
            $html = '<li class="nav item' . $highlight . '"><a href="' . $this->escapeHtml($this->getHref()) . '"';
            $html .= $this->getTitle()
                ? ' title="' . $this->escapeHtml((string)new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($this->getTitle())) . '"'
                : '';
            $html .= $this->getAttributesHtml() . '>';

            if ($this->getIsHighlighted()) {
                $html .= '<strong>';
            }

            $html .= $this->escapeHtml((string)new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($this->getLabel()));

            if ($this->getIsHighlighted()) {
                $html .= '</strong>';
            }

            $html .= '</a></li>';
        }
        }else
        {
            $html = '<li class="nav item' . $highlight . '"><a href="' . $this->escapeHtml($this->getHref()) . '"';
            $html .= $this->getTitle()
                ? ' title="' . $this->escapeHtml((string)new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($this->getTitle())) . '"'
                : '';
            $html .= $this->getAttributesHtml() . '>';

            if ($this->getIsHighlighted()) {
                $html .= '<strong>';
            }

            $html .= $this->escapeHtml((string)new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($this->getLabel()));

            if ($this->getIsHighlighted()) {
                $html .= '</strong>';
            }

            $html .= '</a></li>';
        }
    }
        return $html;
}

    /**
     * Generate attributes' HTML code
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private function getAttributesHtml()
    {
        $attributesHtml = '';
        $attributes = $this->getAttributes();
        if ($attributes) {
            foreach ($attributes as $attribute => $value) {
                $attributesHtml .= ' ' . $attribute . '="' . $this->escapeHtml($value) . '"';
            }
        }

        return $attributesHtml;
    }
}
```

Here the custom link Customer Message only display to user group id is not equal to 1.

step 7
path - app/code/Training/Msg/Block/Msg.php

```
<?php
namespace Training\Msg\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Msg extends Template
{
    public function __construct(Template\Context $context, array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return "Test Message";
    }
}
```

step 8
path - app/code/Training/Msg/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-myemail">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">msg/index/msg</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Customer Message</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
 </page>
```

step 9
path - app/code/Training/Msg/view/frontend/layout/msg_index_msg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
      <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="content">
        <block name="msg" class="Training\Msg\Block\Msg" template="Training_Msg::msg.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

step 10
path - app/code/Training/Msg/view/frontend/templates/msg.phtml

```
<?php echo $block->getTitle(); ?>
```

OR

You can download the module from github link https://github.com/jothibasuj/customer-dashboard-link-based-on-condition

1. Run setup upgrade.
2. Clear cache.
3. set permission to var folder.

Comment: Hi you can try the above code

Comment: sure jothibasu i will update you thanks for u r reply

Comment: hi i am getting https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2621641/3816b4e8374116be35d4dd39260919e4

Comment: i added some print statement in Current.php for checking purpose. now updated the code.

Comment: @NAGARAJUKASA - Did you check working or not?

Comment: Its working we did the changes as per our requirement. thank you so much for helping

Answer (score 3):

First You need create block extents class Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current

your block code like

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Block\View\Element\Html\Link;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;

class Current extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current{

    protected $_customerSession;
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\DefaultPathInterface $defaultPath
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\DefaultPathInterface $defaultPath,
        CustomerSession $CustomerSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_defaultPath = $defaultPath;
        $this->_customerSession = $CustomerSession;
    }


    public function _toHtml(){
          // Here you can check the conditions.
          if($this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute()){
               return parent::_toHtml();
          }
          return '';
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer i will check and get back @jothbasu

Comment: @NAGARAJUKASA - Did you check the above sample code?

Comment: hi @hothibasu that paytrade link how to show for the particular user?

Comment: @NAGARAJUKASA - you can add condition in the toHtml function. please refer the above answer

Comment: hi @jothibasu i have configured my class in using preference in di.xml also but its not working

Comment: @NAGARAJUKASA - please follow the link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131218/how-to-show-a-menu-on-customers-account-conditionally

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61215/discussion-between-jothibasu-and-nagaraju-kasa).